# Full Grid Vs Columnar Grid Layout in Web Designing

Tags: website-design

I have a requirement to design the full grid layout which automatically scales with resolution/screens by width and height. I usually worked around with columnar layout which also can scales but only by width. The main reason they say is to avoid scrolls so that the page can be displayed in all types of screens like tablets etc.

I suggested them not to go for full grid layout but unable to come up with good reasons. Only reason i was able to say was it may damage the elemental level items like font readability, problem with more width scaling and less heigth scaling.

What else can be the problems? The page may have some graphics as well.

The basic reason to suggest that way was i never saw a page which have both grid and scales accordingly to avoid scrolls. Why people dont go for this kind of design?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [The Goldilocks Approach](http://www.designbyfront.com/demo/goldilocks-approach/) for a responsive grid layout?

Comment: no that grid after some width turns to one column...they want fully scaled..it should remain two columns..

Comment: "The main reason they say is to avoid scrolls" = sounds like silly and uneducated marching orders.

Comment: yes i agree...sometimes we have to come across these kinda people.. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible I'm not understanding the requirements, so if my suggestion is too simplistic, apologies.

I think there is a multi-column option available within the Goldilocks Approach, but what I would first do is get back to the basics of the key information they want in their grid columns.

Not scrolling by default is a good option with grids, but, if the default columns displayed must shrink to such a point as no longer rendering the columnar information legibly, then the option of no scrolling doesn't make sense.  So that is where I would start- looking at the size and type of data in the default columns, figuring out whether it makes sense to continue to display in columnar form, regardless of platform and size, or whether, given platform/display restraints, the display can and should change.

The concept of one size fits all is interesting to the point where it's not the size that's the issue, but the object being sized.

Comment: you understood right...but thing is i have mentioned them about elemental sizes but that is not convincing them...anyways i think i am forced to design scaling grid..may end nicely or end up very bad...